# WSL sudo apt trying to use windows file paths

Tags: ubuntu, python, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a few day old install of WSL using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa). I am trying to fix some package issues I was experiencing (specifically gradle) and I'm not finding that `sudo apt --fix-broken install` is breaking because I believe it is trying to use windows file paths mixed with unix file paths?

The error that I think is causing it is `python3: can't open file 'C:\\usr\\bin\\py3clean': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` that `C:` combined with using back-slashes makes me think there is an issue with the navigation but the `/usr/bin/py3clean` path is a legitimate existing one.

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libsasl2-modules
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-apport
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3-apport
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 156 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/249 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 31852 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.21_all.deb ...
python3: can't open file 'C:\\usr\\bin\\py3clean': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
dpkg: warning: old python3-apport package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
python3: can't open file 'C:\\usr\\bin\\py3clean': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.21_all.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-apport package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
python3: can't open file 'C:\\usr\\bin\\py3compile': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3-apport package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.21_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The py3clean file **DOES** exist:

```
$ ll /usr/bin/ | grep py3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root        7813 Mar 13  2020 py3clean*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root       12120 Mar 13  2020 py3compile*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          31 Mar 13  2020 py3versions -> ../share/python3/py3versions.py*
```

Comment: Glad you reposted this over here.  I started to take a look at it on Stack Overflow before realizing it was off-topic there, and often folks *don't* repost on a better site, so I didn't spend much time on it.  From the looks of it, for some reason the *Windows* python executable is being called. What does `which python` and `which python3` return?

Comment: At a guess I'd say you were trying to use a version of `python3` that was built for Windows rather than WSL. Check your $PATH

Comment: I think you're both absolutely right, I updated my python/python3 to point to the windows installation so that I would only have to manage one install location. Now I'm trying to find the old install location and having trouble finding it. apt says it's still installed.

Comment: Right - That's generally a bad idea under WSL, since the Windows Python doesn't understand Linux paths, modules, processes, etc. etc.  Definitely use the Linux Python when in WSL.  As for reverting, that will depend on how you made the change in the first place.  It isn't likely to be something as simple as an alias, since the `apt` code should see through that.  `update-alternatives` shouldn't let you do it either.  Probably a symlink?  I'd still be interested in `which python` and `which python3`, though.

Comment: I had manually remapped the `/usr/bin/python` to the python3 and `/usr/bin/python3` to the windows installation. `which python python3` just pointed to `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python3` respectively